# Bootstrap: Form submit not working in modal box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Below is model box and i am using it for login. When i click on button(both) page just reload it self. I checked in firebug and found something like this.
**localhost\index.php?submit=Login**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <form method="post" id="login" name="login" action="login_exec.php" role="form">

        <div class="modal-content login-modal">
            <div class="modal-header login-modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <font color="#288DCB"><h3 class="modal-titles text-center" id="loginModalLabel">AUTHENTICATION</h3></font>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="login-tab">
                        <!-- Tab panes -->
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active text-center" id="emphome">
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <span id="login_fail" class="response_error" style="display: none;">Loggin failed, please try again.</span>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login_username" placeholder="Email Address" required="required">
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="help-block has-error" id="email-error"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" required="required">
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="help-block has-error" id="password-error"></span>
                                </div>

                                <input type="submit" value="Login" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                <button type="submit" value=" Send" class="btn btn-success" id="submit" />
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I am not able to find the reason why it is working like this. I tried button and input type but same result.

Here is my javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#login").on("submit", function(e) {      
        e.preventDefault;
 alert("failure");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "logic_exec.php", //process to mail
        data: $('form.login').serialize(),
        success: function(msg){
            $("#thanks").html(msg) //hide button and show thank you
            $("#form-content").modal('hide'); //hide popup  
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("failure");
        }
    });
});
});
  </script>
```

I am using `alert("failure");` to check my script is working on button click but it is not working. I think this event is not firing.

Comment: What is posted in firebug when you click the input type. Remember to set persist ON in firebug console and Net tabs.

Comment: did you use event listener eg. `onclick` on the submit button?

Comment: there could be a possibility of your modal code inside a form tag itself, please check for that.

Answer (score -1):

To get a modal to submit without reloading the entire page, the modal "submit" button needs to call javascript `type="button" onclick="submitmyinfo();"` instead of a submit.  The javascript function can then use ajax to submit the information, if successful, you can do whatever you need, like close the modal.